# Catching Keycombination on all windows in WPF without adding event on every window

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to add a KeyPress event on Application level which checks certain key combination whenever it is pressed.

If keycombination is matched. I want to open a window on the current window that is executing.

How can I do this.

**Edit**

I want to add KeyPress event on Application class so that it can capture key pressed on all the windows. 
One way to do is, I can go to every Window and add event on each window.
But what if number of windows is large enough. this is what my scenario is.

So I was trying to do something on Application class to do the same work.

How can I do

Comment: Is this within your program or for *any* program (e.g. Word, Visual Studio, etc.)?

Comment: @ChrisF: It is within my own application. VS

Comment: OK - then what key combination do you want to check for?

Comment: @ChrisF: I want to catch Atl+Ctrl+O for now..but there are many other keys also...What I want is to add this Event on Applicaiton class so that it can be handled everywhere...and i need not open every window and add KeyPress event.

Comment: It would be worth updating your question with this information making it clear what you are trying to achieve. It will help you get relevant answers.

Comment: My mistake - you're right what I suggested would need to go in every `Window` XAML file.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `PreviewKeyDown` event. This is sent by each control before they process the key themselves.

As an alternative, you can use [CommandBindings](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-command-bindings-and-custom-commands).

Answer (score 0):

As a clean and simple solution, maybe you could use something like this:
Instead of you manually add the event on every window, you make the computer do it for you.

```
    private void AssignEventHandlers()
    {
        foreach (Window window in Application.Current.Windows)
        {
            //if (window != Application.Current.MainWindow)
                window.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Input.KeyEventHandler(window_KeyDown);
        }
    }

    void window_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // MessageBox.Show(e.Key.ToString());
        if (System.Windows.Input.Keyboard.Modifiers == (System.Windows.Input.ModifierKeys.Control | System.Windows.Input.ModifierKeys.Alt)
            && e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.O)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(System.Windows.Input.Keyboard.Modifiers.ToString() + " " + e.Key.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Sources:

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/sample-code/SilverlightWPFandXAML/aeac920b-a64f-43b3-976b-2f7c91a5212b/wpf-get-all-windows-in-an-application.aspx

http://www.codegain.com/articles/wpf/miscellaneous/how-to-detect-ctrl-alt-key-combinations-in-wpf.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to use Low-level **Windows API** hooks from **C#** 
something like this:
 http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/CSLLKeyboard.aspx

this will involve code using  System.Runtime.InteropServices and user32.dll

```
...

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, LowLevelKeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);
// and the code to create the event handler, etc... See more on the referred article.
...
```